# If $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are independent and identically distributed and $S_n$ is their sum, prove that $\mathbb{E}[X_i \mid S_n]=\mathbb{E}[X_1 \mid S_n]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Consider the following exercise

> If $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are independent with same distribution and $S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$, prove that
> $$\mathbb{E}[X_i \mid S_n]=\frac{S_n}{n}$$
> Proof: Since the variables have the same distribution we have that:
> $$S_n=\mathbb{E}[S_n \mid S_n]=\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=0}^n X_i \mid S_n \right]=\sum_{i=0}^n\mathbb{E}[X_i \mid S_n]=n \cdot \mathbb{E}[X_i \mid S_n]$$

I'm trying to figure out why the fact that the variables have the same distribution implies that they have the same conditional expectation with respect to $S_n$. I tried to see if the expected values of the variables on the sets of the form $S_n^{-1}(A)$ (with $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ borel set) are equal (I mean that $\mathbb{E}[X_1\mathbf{1}_{S_n^{-1}(A)}]=\mathbb{E}[X_i\mathbf{1}_{S_n^{-1}(A)}]$), because this fact would give me the thesis, but I don't know how to do it. Any suggestion on how to demonstrate the equality between the conditional expectations?

Comment: You are only asking about the final equality in the Proof.  I would have thought i.i.d. and exchangeability was sufficient.

Comment: @Henry What do you mean by exchangeability?

Comment: I am saying the i.i.d. property means $(X_1,X_2, \ldots,X_{i-1},X_i,X_{i+1},\ldots, X_n)$ has the same joint distribution as  $(X_i,X_2, \ldots,X_{i-1},X_1,X_{i+1},\ldots, X_n)$ swapping $X_1$ and $X_i$, so they are exchangeable.  So the conditional distributions of the first term given the sum of all the terms are the same, and so the conditional expectations are the same.  You can have exchangeability without independence (e.g. sampling without replacement) but here you have both.

Comment: See [Wikipedia on exchangeable random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_random_variables)

Comment: So, in this case it seems to work because of independence, since $\mathbb{P}((X_1,X_2) \in A \times B)=\mathbb{P}(X_1 \in A,\ X_2 \in B)=\mathbb{P}(X_1 \in A)\mathbb{P}(X_2 \in B)\\=\mathbb{P}(X_2 \in A)\mathbb{P}(X_1 \in B)=\mathbb{P}((X_2,X_1) \in A\times B)$. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exercise is a direct application of the following proposition, with $X=(X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n)$ and $Y=(X_{i_1},X_{i_2},\cdots,X_{i_n})$ :

If $X=(X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n)$ and $Y=(Y_1,Y_2,\cdots,Y_n)$ are identically distributed and $f$ and $g$ are measurable functions, then:
$$ E[f(X)\mid g(X)=z]=E[f(Y)\mid g(Y)=z] \tag{1}$$
Proof:
$$\int E[f(X)\mid g(X)]I_A(g(X))dP_{\Omega}=\int f(X)I_A(g(X))dP_{\Omega} $$
But: $$\int E[f(X)\mid g(X)]I_A(g(X))dP_{\Omega}=\int E[f(X)\mid g(\mathbf x) ]I_A(g(\mathbf x))dP_X$$
And: $$\int f(X)I_A(g(X))dP_{\Omega}=\int f(\mathbf x)I_A(g(\mathbf x))dP_X$$
Therefore, for $(1)$ to be valid, it is enough that: $$\int E[f(X)\mid g(\mathbf x)]I_A(g(\mathbf x))dP_X=\int f(\mathbf x)I_A(g(\mathbf x))dP_X$$
But this last equation, and therefore $E[f(X)\mid g(\mathbf x)]$, only depends on the distribution of $X$.